# How to understand Namespace of outlook 2007 data store

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

Firstly , I am a freshmen to outlook add-in development,Recently I read some learning material from MSDN or other tutorial, The First thing makes me confused is if I want to find something like a certain **Appointment** or **Meeting Request** from inbox, I should firstly use `Application.GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)` to get a `NameSpace` instead of getting some kind of object like `Folder` or `Appointment` Collections and so on.

I don't understand the Data Store Access pattern of Outlook 2007 in Add-in development. I hope someone can help me better understand Data store access of outlook 2007.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **[MAPI Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842468.aspx)** is required to interact with an Outlook Data Store. [`Application.Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866436.aspx) is interchangeable with `Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")`. You can think of a session as a connection to the Outlook Data Store.

To retrieve appointments, you can use [`Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866724).

```cs
Outlook.Folder appointmentStore = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar) as Outlook.Folder;
string apptSubject = string.Empty;
foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem appt in appointments.Items.OfType<Outlook.AppointmentItem>())
  apptSubject = appt.Subject;
```

Comment: Thanks, What do you mean `required` ? It means `better`? Actually I found someone uses `Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)` in some code examples instead of using the `Session`.

Comment: They are equivalent. `Session == GetNamespace("MAPI")`

Comment: So ,That means MAPI reference is the necessary thing on the learning path of Outlook 2007 add-in development. Is it Correct?Thanks

Comment: Yes - you need to reference a **MAPI Session** for many Outlook integration tasks. It depends on what customizations you are performing.

Comment: Hi ,Ninja, need you help check something, I think `session`  is the MAPI Way to access outlook dataitems, and `GetNamespace` is the Object model and PIA another way . Is it correct? Thanks

Comment: [`Outlook.Namespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.namespace.aspx) is PIA (*Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook*). Both `Session` and `GetNamespace()` return `Outlook.Namespace`. **PIA** provides multiple ways of establishing a **MAPI Session**.

Comment: So, both are outlook object model and PIA ways to access data items, correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15382/discussion-between-malai-kuangren-and-sliverninja)